# Executing an SQL query to order a list without having to store it as a java object?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a table in MySQL with 3 columns: CategoryID, Score, dateTime. I need to find top 4 categories with the highest Scores. I must also consider the timestamps each of these scores has because if I score high in a category at an old date, but low on a category on a more recent date, then the recent Score dominates what the score of the category is. Is there a query in SQL to generate a result set? I have done it in java by storing the data as objects, but if there is a more efficient way, I prefer to do that.

Note: pickRandom is an ArrayList of Strings, and ignore the method checkIfThere()

```
Scores prevScore = new Scores(0, "AD",  new Timestamp(0));
            while (rs.next()) {

                categoryID = rs.getString("categoryID");
                int relScore = rs.getInt("relevanceScore");
                Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp("date_time");

                Scores currScore = new Scores(relScore, categoryID, ts);

                // ensures that a Random Barrier Cateogry is prompted
                if ((currScore.getScore() >= prevScore.getScore() && (currScore.getDate().compareTo(prevScore.getDate()) > 0) && !checkIfThere(user, categoryID))) {
                    pickRandom.add(categoryID);
                    prevScore = currScore;
                }
            }
```

### Edit:

Table: **Scores**

```
'AD', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51' 
'DC', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51' 
'DO', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51' 
'EC', '8.087601288990395', '2015-08-26 14:59:53' 
'EC', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51'
```

Comment: a common strategy for early on sql guys is to bring things into objects and wrap their heads around it that way. No worries. Show the table structure and some sample data. You will find the result to be much faster, plus no GC !

Comment: to publish a table structure, do something like `show create table tableName`

Comment: show create table Scores: 'AD', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51'
'DC', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51'
'DO', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51'
'EC', '8.087601288990395', '2015-08-26 14:59:53'
'EC', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51'

Comment: unsure how to publish it but this is what the rows look like

Comment: let's say you get into the mysql command prompt. Then enter `show create table scores;`   When I do it in the GUI tool I can't easily (fast) get the results out of the grids

Comment: ---------------Thanks!

Comment: Can you define "old date"?  Presumably your score column is a floating point number, right?  Also, here's a fiddle for this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e00a/3/0

Comment: Yes scores are floats. And by old date, I meant that if there was an older date with a higher score than a  recent date with a lower score, then the more recent date with the lower score should stand for the category. For example: Sept 6 has a score of 100, Sept 9 has a score of 75. Assuming both of these scores are in the same category, the score of 75 on Sept 9 should stand as the score for the category

Comment: Also, your fiddle picks the max Scores, not the most recent dates with highest score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give something like the following a try. The `inr` derived table is banking on a unique time/second timesplit. Perhaps can be enhanced with the id column. The `inr` will get all 6 categories in my sample data. The outer will join and say it only wants 4.

```
create table scores
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    categoryID varchar(10) not null,
    relevanceScore float not null,
    date_time datetime not null
);
truncate table scores;
insert scores (categoryID,relevanceScore,date_time) values
('AD', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51'), 
('DC', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51'), 
('DO', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51'), 
('EC', '8.087601288990395', '2015-08-26 14:59:53'), 
('EC', '110', '2015-08-26 14:59:51'),
('OLD1', '110', '2014-08-26 14:59:51'),
('OLD2', '110', '2014-08-26 14:59:51');
```

### Option A: (top 4 by date_time DESC)

```
select s.* from scores s 
join 
( select categoryID,max(date_time) as maxdt 
  from scores 
  group by categoryId 
) inr 
on inr.categoryID=s.categoryID and inr.maxdt=s.date_time 
order by s.date_time desc 
limit 4; 

+----+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | categoryID | relevanceScore | date_time           |
+----+------------+----------------+---------------------+
|  4 | EC         |         8.0876 | 2015-08-26 14:59:53 |
|  1 | AD         |            110 | 2015-08-26 14:59:51 |
|  2 | DC         |            110 | 2015-08-26 14:59:51 |
|  3 | DO         |            110 | 2015-08-26 14:59:51 |
+----+------------+----------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### option B: (top 4 by relevanceScore DESC)

```
select s.* from scores s 
join 
( select categoryID,max(date_time) as maxdt 
  from scores 
  group by categoryId 
) inr 
on inr.categoryID=s.categoryID and inr.maxdt=s.date_time 
order by s.relevanceScore desc
limit 4; 
+----+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | categoryID | relevanceScore | date_time           |
+----+------------+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 | AD         |            110 | 2015-08-26 14:59:51 |
|  2 | DC         |            110 | 2015-08-26 14:59:51 |
|  3 | DO         |            110 | 2015-08-26 14:59:51 |
|  6 | OLD1       |            110 | 2014-08-26 14:59:51 |
+----+------------+----------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I think it is safe with sticking with the dt coming out of the `inr` since it is by category, then the outer joins on that category & dt. As such I don't believe the use of id's in joining is necessary. Surely any peer here can comment otherwise if I am wrong. And lastly, hopefully you have an index on categoryID. Good luck

Comment: or rather a composite index on (categoryID,date_time), which would be a nice covering index for `inr`, and useful in outer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

---

```
select * from Scores order by date_time,relevanceScore;
```

Comment: This would not account for repeats of scores in the same category, but different dates. I solved for this by storing as an object and ordering the objects.