# Count Records in MySQL Where the Most Recent Date in A Table Falls Within A Certain Range

Tags: mysql

In one table is stored the dates a user has logged in (each log-in is a new record.)  In another table, the typical user/account data.  I only want to count the number of records in the main account table that have users that have not logged in since ....

Example query:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.ID) 
FROM ptpl_accounts a 
   LEFT JOIN ptpl_statistics_logins l ON l.OwnerID = a.ID 
WHERE LAST(l.LastAccess) > '2010-01-01 00:00:00';
```

This appears to be an incorrect use of the LAST command?  What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: how about looking into aggregates ... group by **having**

Comment: Yeah but how do I only show based on the most recent date in record?  i.e. if I group by l.LastAccess > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' it's going to look at all of the LastAccess records instead of only the most recent one.  I need it to make the decision based only on the most recent record.

Comment: how about a select userid,max(theDate) with a group by theDate ... obviously with a join....let's call that a derived table. Use that wrapped inside a select statement on the outside. The select stmt on the outside has its own where clause

Comment: as you know, it always help to show sample data (say 5 to 10 rows). and a little verbiage, and expected results. Saves everyone time. Sqlfiddle's would break our hearts either :)

Comment: Indeed.  Thanks for your gentle rebuke. :)  So, how does this look?  `SELECT COUNT(a.ID) FROM ptpl_accounts a WHERE  (SELECT MAX(l.LastAccess) FROM ptpl_statistics_logins l WHERE l.OwnerID = a.ID) < '2014-01-01 00:00:00';` 

It seems to work, just wanted a second opinion @Drew

Comment: whatever generates a decent `explain` and performance. I will try to put together a derived table inner chunk example with data when I get a chance. But it would generally follow the pattern of the `inr` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32235673/1816093) Good luck :)